# ios 9 NData return nil even calling https url

Tags: ios, swift, ssl

the following code always return nil.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-contentdelivery-mobilehub-462838928/tree.jpg")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

2015-10-31 16:25:16.795 test2[59798:19080494] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

The url already https, and aws s3 provide TLS 1.2 SSL. You can try the above url in your browser, and check the certification and connection information. Looks like already met the ios 9 requirement, but still got nil for data. I don't want set "allow arbitrary loads" = YES in Info.plist. Any idea? Did I missing something? Is NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) using http instead of https?

Comment: you can add an exception for amazon and its subdomains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS wrote in their blog, that they are not ATS ready yet:
https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2QM69ZE6BGTYX/Preparing-Your-Apps-for-iOS-9

They suggest to define an opt-out rule until they are ready:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
            <key>amazonaws.com</key>
            <dict>
                  <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                  <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                  <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                  <false/>
                  <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                  <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>amazonaws.com.cn</key>
            <dict>
                  <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                  <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                  <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                  <false/>
                  <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                  <true/>
            </dict>
      </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

until amazon is ready you could put the following into your info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>amazonaws.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```